# Swing Worker Thread Causing Lag During Large XML Parse

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, xml-parsing, swingworker

In my `public static main[]` method I create the GUI using:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        app = new Main();
    }
});
```

And from a Swing button click I create a Swing Worker thread using:

```
LoadFile lf = new LoadFile();
lf.execute();
```

Where the `execute()` command calls the `doInBackground()` method of the class that extends `SwingWorker`. The method accesses no resources outside of the method. The job it's doing is reading in a file of some 227,000 rows with about 15 columns (300MB~ in size). This takes about 12 seconds.

The `doInBackground()` thread consists of this code:

```
@Override
protected ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> doInBackground() throws Exception 
{
Map <String, String> profMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
profMap.putAll(Settings.xmlMap);

ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> tempProfData = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>();

try {
    File fXmlFile = new File(Settings.datasetFile);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName(profMap.get("Node Name"));

    for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) 
    {
    Node nNode = nList.item(i);

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
    {
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        int count = 0;

        LinkedHashMap<String, String> tempMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        for (String key : profMap.keySet())
        {
            if (count >= 2)
            {
                String value = eElement.getElementsByTagName(profMap.get(key)).item(0).getTextContent();
                tempMap.put(key, value);
            }

            count++;
        }    

        tempProfData.add(tempMap);
    }
    }

} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return tempProfData;
}
```

While this is occurring I have a loading animation on screen but it can get a bit laggy while it's happening. The CPU seems to be running at 100% for the application in Task Manager.

Is such a large task slowing down the application or have I got something tied in a knot? The GUI doesn't freeze completely, but if you click something it will sometimes lag visibly for about half a second until the thread is done.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Part of the problem might be the continuos resizing of tempProfData, maybe consider supplying a larger initial value. Don't forget that temporary variables can add gc overhead

Comment: @MadProgrammer I made he size of the array the size of the dataset but it didn't affect the time, a second was saved but the GUI remained laggy